# How to estimate 3D hand-pose from an image with MMPose

Tags: 3d, tracking, pose

I'm trying to estimate the 3-D hand-pose from an image with [MMPose](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmpose), but I cannot figure out how to do that.

I couldn't figure it out based on the documentation and also creating an issue in their repo didn't answer my question.